# Views exposed filters and using AJAX

Tags: ajax, views

I have a view in which I have used Exposed filters and load the content using AJAX. The problem is whenever I apply any filter, first page is loaded properly but when there are more result and I go to next page using pager my filters are reset and wrong next page is loaded,because javascript is getting called after AJAX call. Any suggestions how to overcome this issue?